# Ensure that an inferred type is assignable to a specified one without casting

Tags: typescript, types

I have sometimes the case, that I want to ensure that a specific value V (like an object) is assignable to a given type T. The problem is, if I assign the value V to a variable/constant of that type T, then I lose the infered type information of the value V, which is needed to ensure more type safty in the next step.

Here is an example where I want to ensure that a statically defined object only has string keys and string values. Certainly, in this example you do not really need the type checker in order to define this object properly without mistakes, but there are more complicated types wehre the type checker becomes handy.

```js
const fruitMenu = <const>{
    "apple": "pie",
    "banana": "split",
    "strawberry": "ice",
}

type Fruits = keyof typeof fruitMenu // "apple" | "banana" | "strawberry"

const fruitMenu2 = <const>{
    "apple": "pie",
    "banana": "split",
    "strawberry": "ice",
    0: 2,  // Error. Only strings please
}
```

If I want to ensure the string-key-string-value thing, I could do somehting like

```js
const fruitMenu: Record<string, string> = <const>{
    "apple": "pie",
    "banana": "split",
    "strawberry": "ice",
}
type Fruits = keyof typeof fruitMenu
```

But then the type of fruitMenu will be Record<string, string> regardless of the real value and the Fruits type is just string. But I want Fruits to be "apple" | "banana" | "strawberry" in order to have more type safty eg in this function:

```js
type FoodTypes = (typeof fruitMenu)[Fruits]
function getFoodType(fruit: Fruits): FoodTypes {
    return fruitMenu[fruit]
}
```

How can I achive the type safty in the object definition and the accessing part without code duplications (DRY principle)?

Comment: Whatever I try, I end up having a useless constant, a noisy function call beside the original declaration or even worse code duplications by defining the value and its type separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is only possible by creating an extra function that automatically infers the given type parameter and requires the parameter to match the predefined type at the same time. By returning the parameter as is you don't have to specify anything twice.

```js
// Workaround to prevent any type inference for the return type 
// of our type-checking function. 
// Type inference should happen only for the parameter.
export type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

// The predefined type
type FruitMenuLike = Record<string, string>

// this function checks if a given value matches the predefined type, but returns the inferred type.
function softTypeCheck<T extends FruitMenuLike>(value: T & FruitMenuLike): NoInfer<T> {
    return value
}

// Single DRY definition of the real instance preserving its inferred type
const fruitMenu = softTypeCheck(<const>{
    "apple": "pie",
    "banana": "split",
    "strawberry": "ice",
})
```